# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi formulario tome el 100% de su contenedor y no el 50% en bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Estoy realizando el diseño de un formulario con Bootstrap, a mi formulario le di un width del 50% (w-50), pero al momento de adaptarlo a pantallas mas pequeñas este me sigue tomando el 50% quedando un formulario muy pequeño, me gastaría que en pantalla mas chicas tome el 100%, ¿Alguien sabe como realizar esto?, comparto mi código

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <form class="border border-1 rounded p-4 m-auto w-50">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Registro</h3>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Las Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta verificar el sistema de grid de bootstrap. Por ejemplo si quieres que tome el total del ancho rodea tu form con un div con la clase `row` pues este estaria dentro de dentro de esto puedes decir que cuando este en un dispositivo pequeño use `sm-12` (que tome el total del ancho) de la misma forma para tablets que tome solo la mitad del ancho `md-6` y asi sucesivamente mas info https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar la clase `mx-auto` y no indicarle `m-50`, demás que al div padre lo puedes hacer flex. Revisa si ese es el resultado esperado.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="d-flex flex-center flex-column flex-column-fluid">
        <form class="border border-1 rounded p-4 mx-auto">
            <h3 class="mb-3">Registro</h3>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Las Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema es que si yo le pongo mx-auto con el d-flex el formulario me queda muy chico para pantallas grandes, yo quiere que el formulario se quede como lo puese en el ejemplo, pero cuando se cambie a pantallas mas pequeñas tome el 100% @javdromero